# Linq check if all collections have at least one common item

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I'm working on a bit of code at the moment and I grasp the concept, but I'm not sure how I'd go about expressing it in LINQ-to-objects.

The scenario I have is this:

> A tree with hierarchical data whereby some items can be relocated using drag-drop to other parent items.

I want to support multiple items being dragged, an example of the tree is as follows:

- Period

  - Instance
- Period

  - Instance

Each view model item in the hierarchy derives from a base type on which I'm exposing an `IReadOnlyList<Type>` which states which hierarchy types each hierarchy item is happy being relocated to as a child.

On the `PreviewDragEnter` event I'm already checking that every item being dragged actually supports being relocated.

The problem I actually want to solve is how to check each of these readonly lists for at least 1 type in common so I can be certain that every item being dragged can be relocated to the same target.

I realise a 1-1 `.Any()` check could be done if I was going from one collection to the next, but how do I do this for an arbitrary number?

I've got something like this so far, but I'm not certain it's correct and it certainly doesn't look optimal:

```
private void RadTreeView_PreviewDragStarted(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeViewDragEventArgs e)
{
    var items = e.DraggedItems.Cast<HierarchyItemViewModel>();

    // Every item being dragged must support being dragged
    if (items.Any(i => i.ValidReorgTargets.Count == 0))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (items.All(i => HasOneTypeInCommonWithOthers(i, items.Except(new[] { i }))))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}

private bool HasOneTypeInCommonWithOthers(HierarchyItemViewModel item, IEnumerable<HierarchyItemViewModel> others)
{
    return others.All(i => i.ValidReorgTargets.Intersect(item.ValidReorgTargets).Any());
}
```

Anything better than that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if (items.Select(i => i.ValidReorgTargets).Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1.Intersect(i2)).Any())
{
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

In other words, if there is a common intersection across all the `ValidReorgTargets` collections then they can be relocated to the same target.

Answer (score 0):

(I would have given you compilable code but I'm not exactly sure what's going on in your example as you change your terminology from instance to view model item to a base type to a hierarchy type to readonly lists to a HierarchyViewItemModel and so on.  So, just words follow.)

Enumerate each type on each of your readonly lists, accumulating into a Dictionary<type,int> the number of instances of each type found.  Assuming no duplicates in any readonly list (which you can remove with Distinct) then the keys of all elements in your dictionary where the accumulated value is the number of readonly lists you started with are the types you want.

Accumulating the dictionary is O(n) where n is the total number of types in all the readonly lists to add to the Dictionary (from MSDN we learn that Dictionary.Add is amortized O(1) ... or can be if you take some care when expanding the Dictionary), determining the number of types (keys) that have value == number of your readonly lists is O(m) where m is the number of distinct types in all of the readonly lists.  Thus, the algorithm is linear in the total size of all the elements of your readonly lists.